# Debezium Connector - Communication link failure

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

i got issue when connect local mysql using docker

> {"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nUnable to connect: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint /connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate"}

here my configuration :

```
 {
  "name": "inventory-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "mysql",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "debezium",
    "database.password": "dbz",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.include.list": "inventory",
    "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval":"true",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory"
  }
}
```

this my mysql docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: quay.io/debezium/example-mysql:1.9
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=mysqluser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium
    volumes:
      - ./mysqldb_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

networks:
  zookeeper_default:
    external:
      name: zookeeper_default
```

let me know if you know anything, thanks

Comment: You've not attached that Zookeeper network to the mysql container. If you're not familiar with docker compose networking, you should put all services in the same file

Comment: @OneCricketeer I get the same issue when im trying to connect my local mysql instance to kafka , i have checked and double checked the configs , everything seems to be okay still get this same error. my zooker and kafka connect and debezium run on containers

Comment: @SithijaPiyumanThewaHettige Please open a new post and show your own configs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `"database.hostname": "mysql"`

If you're running Debezium outside of Docker, you should be using localhost here, and similarly for `database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers`.

Otherwise, you need to ensure that the Debezium server and mysql are attached to same Docker network. Use `docker network` and `docker inspect` commands to debug this, and exec into both containers and try to `ping` in the both directions using their service names